# How to initialize an array of objects in Pascal?

Tags: arrays, object, queue, pascal, freepascal

I have a queue defined

```
Queue = object
    head, tail : pNode;
    constructor init;
    procedure insert(what : data);
    ...
end;
```

Where

```
constructor Queue.init;
  begin
  new(head);
  tail := head;
  head^.next := nil;
end;
```

Then I have `P : array[0..9] of Queue;` and want to initialize queues in it like `for i:=0 to 9 do P[i].init;`, but the compiler complains that P does not seem to be initialized.

So how to initialize array of objects properly? Thanks.

Comment: Show the code where you declare `P` and your initialization code. Also, never change the name of the constructor: always use `Create`.

Comment: You'd need to call it as `for i := 0 to 9 do P[i] := Queue.init;`.

Comment: @TLama It says incompatible types, got QWordBool, expected queue

Comment: Please don't say "I have something, and I use it like this". Post the **actual code** you're using that the compiler is not happy with, so we can help you. We can't troubleshoot code you haven't actually provided, and the made-up-on-the-fly code might hide the actual problem.

Comment: I think this is just a misunderstanding, @KenWhite, this <i>is</i> the actual code (the trouble can't be anywhere else, I'm sure!).

Comment: @mirgee please, instead of guessing and polluting internet with rtfm-style questions read some programming book first, e.g. http://wiki.freepascal.org/Object_Pascal_Tutorial Stack Overflow was not meant to be a tutorial site (see e.g. [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254933/answering-questions-which-ask-for-effort-guidance-not-spoon-fed-solutions)). I believe you did not intend it you just did not realize. BTW: **Objects were obsoleted** by [Classes](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Object_Oriented_Programming_with_FreePascal_and_Lazarus#Class) some decade ago

Comment: @xmojmr This is not the place for such a discussion, but... I don't see what's wrong wrong with my questions, even after reading the discussion you refer to and respective articles on the help centre. By no means I want to pollute this site. I love the concept of SE and want to contribute well. I realize these question are basic and of course I did some research before asking. If I'd found the answers though, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: @xmojmr Moreover, this way of initializing array of objects I actually found in a book.

Comment: @mirgee ```Free Pascal``` is a set of tools, mainly the free cross-platform compiler. ```Pascal language``` was designed by ```Niklaus Wirth``` and later extended by ```Borland company``` into ```Object Pascal language``` flavor marketed as ```Delphi```. In its time it was VERY popular and millions of lines of code exists (I wrote some too). The ```object keyword``` became deprecated feature in ~1995. This and ```pointer``` and ```record``` still play its role. But for tutorial on linked lists etc. Google for ```class keyword``` and ```Delphi``` - much easier. What "book" do you read and why?

Comment: @xmojmr I've heard that before. I know Pascal has been superseded by Delphi... It is still language of choice for teaching algorithms to beginners at most schools. At mine too. I'm reading Základy algoritmizace from Miroslav Virius... To pass the finals.

Comment: @mirgee if you want to run Pascal examples from the book (1st edition written in the past century) then **1** replace ```record``` with ```class``` **2** replace ```object``` with ```class``` **3** replace ```^.``` with ```.``` **4** remove differences between T and ^T there is no need for 2 names for 1 thing **5** add ```public``` visibility modifier **6** replace ```delete x``` with ```x.Free``` **6** name constructors and destructors ```Create``` and ```Destroy``` **7** when looking for code help then search for ```Delphi``` (language) you will find many examples and answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init only calls the constructor. The initialization is done by calling new with the constructor as second argument, try

```
for i:=0 to 9 do 
   new(P[i], Queue.Init));
```

Comment: It throws 3 errors:
1.) pointer type expected, but got queue
2.) illegal expression
3.) ) expected, but identifier init found

Comment: Aargh, yes correct. Usually you work with pointers, not static objects. I guess that then the warning is stale. You can fillchar the object to zero it.

Comment: What does it mean 'the warning is stale'? How do I fillchar an object? I choose your answer as correct anyway.

Comment: fillchar(p,sizeof(p),#0);